# android how to make EditText larger when you clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

In my activity i have eight `EditText` widgets.
Because there are so many of them, after the user is  filling them ,the activity looks crowded and unordered.
I want to make the `EditText` with only one line and when the `EditText` is clicked, it will become bigger - the height and width of all the words it contains.
How do i do that? 
This is my code for a single `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EDITtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the textsize (aka font size)?

Answer (score 0):

here you have choose only one line it means that it will get text only for one line son edit text will be only of one line and it will not grow after one line

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
public void onBtnClicked(View v) 
{
    EditText current_text_box = (EditText) v;
    Intent intent = new Intent(ObservationActivity.this,    TexteditorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("start_text", current_text_box.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("start_position", current_text_box.getSelectionStart());
    startActivityForResult(intent, v.getId()); // the getid() identifies the

}
```

> This is when you click EditText Call new activity That activity contain big size of EditText When you save that it will back to old stage ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
EditText current_text_box = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.current_eidttext);
current_text_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {
        current_text_box.setTextScaleX(size);
    current_text_box.setTextSize(size);

}
```